# How to share my modern Skype profile not with link and not by telling primary email?

Tags: skype

How to share my profile in Skype?

I can not use link and I don't want to tell my primary email I used to set up this profile. Currently Skype doesn't have unique skype names anymore.

For example, how do I know my outlook email ID for example, that MS automatically created for me to share with people? How to I tell someone how to find me?

This is the "call" I have got and I do have skype on my phone:

[image: Skype profile, Join conversation, Welcome to Skype]

Comment: Why you can't use link? You can ask the others to share their addresses. Or you can create a new account and use that.

Comment: whats wrong with your skype user name?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft it doesn't have unique skype names anymore.

Comment: @MátéJuhász do you think a man should type 100500 symbols nonsense link in the search field of Skype App?

Comment: @mevsme: one of the great things of using computers / smartphones is that you can copy & paste links:), even if the app doesn't support following links.

Comment: @MátéJuhász tell it to a chinese mother that has no idea what is copy\paste

Comment: are you here to get support and find solution, or to express your frustration over the change?

Comment: @MátéJuhász so what's you suggestion? How do I know my outlook email ID for example, that MS automatically created for me to share with people? How to I tell someone how to find me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HatScripts](https://hatscripts.com/addskype/) to share your Skype as a link or a button. Here is the URL syntax:

```
https://hatscripts.com/addskype/?MYSKYPEID
```

It's useful to share in e-mail signatures or on the websites.

Comment: mate are you kidding me?) I need to tell mommy how to find me in Skype App, which she sees at first in her life and not tell her my primary email. Tell in the messanger that has no built in browser or desktop version so she could not copy\paste stuff. And also modern new skype accounts doesn't have Skype ID\Name\Whatever unique

Comment: @mevsme If you ask mommy to click on the link, her Skype will automatically call you. No brainer.

Comment: **kenorb** this is the "call" I have got and I do have skype on my phone. https://pp.userapi.com/c841032/v841032816/77d27/VW9yrqhhzZQ.jpg @kenorb